How does istio-ingressgateway and istio-proxy in terms of keepalive?
I'm trying to understand how istio-ingressgateway and istio-proxy works with keepalive.

istio-ingressgateway


In default, istio ingressgateway doesn't seem to have any keepalives, and I found that it can be turned on using EnvoyFilter. Why is keepalive turned off in default?
I have ALB in front of the istio ingressgateway. Should I turn on keepalive in istio ingressgateway for better performance?


istio-proxy


How does istio-proxy keepalive work? For example, I have an application pod configured with istio-proxy sidecar. Running netstat in istio-proxy container, I filtered the sockets with destination port 3306 (mysql). I see that the sockets bound to the application have keepalive configured. However, the sockets bound to the istio-proxy doesn't seem to have keepalive configured (see the result below). The outgoing request will have a network hop of application -> istio-proxy -> mysql. Does the result below mean that the application -> istio-proxy has keepalive, but the istio-proxy -> mysql doesn't have keepalive? (I don't have DestinationRule configured)

istio-proxy@api-server-78546676ff-jmz7n:/$ netstat -napot | grep :3306
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:44666        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:35796        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:53726        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:38004        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:37970        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:45754        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:37980        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:45766        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:35578        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:48336        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:60982        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:46468        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:53656        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:42940        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:37938        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:54056        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:52402        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:43016        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:33462        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:40306        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:37786        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:55524        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:43272        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:58828        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:38590        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:33442        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:35348        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:34652        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:43446        10.2.87.210:3306        TIME_WAIT   -                    timewait (53.17/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:37988        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.2.59.79:48448        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED 24/envoy             off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:37956        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6565.21/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:33440        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6628.60/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:43440        10.2.87.210:3306        TIME_WAIT   -                    timewait (53.17/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:43266        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (5580.06/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:37974        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6566.74/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:43008        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (5876.89/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:46464        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6003.36/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:37996        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6574.42/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:37982        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6568.31/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:45752        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (7193.17/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:44660        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (5714.30/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:37778        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6261.88/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:55508        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6510.68/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:42934        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6758.30/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:54054        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (5967.71/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:48440        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6667.33/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:35564        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6494.90/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:60972        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6313.46/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:40304        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6425.69/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:35780        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (5678.33/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:35338        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (5914.68/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:37926        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6519.52/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:53712        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6544.57/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:53640        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6525.79/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:52388        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6091.58/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:58822        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6069.28/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:33456        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6629.91/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:38582        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6032.44/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:45758        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6687.26/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:48332        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6592.42/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 10.2.59.79:34650        10.2.87.210:3306        ESTABLISHED -                    keepalive (6472.32/0/0)


You are confusing TCP keepalive with HTTP keepalive.

TCP keepalive is about detecting connection loss in idle connections. It  has absolutely nothing to do with performance. This is what gets shown in your netstat output.
HTTP keeplive is about reusing the same underlying TCP connection for multiple HTTP/1 requests (irrelevant for HTTP/2 and HTTP/3). This affects performance.

HTTP keepalive is only relevant for HTTP/1 connections, i.e. not for your mysql traffic. TCP keepalive is relevant for your mysql traffic, but has nothing to do with performance. So tuning it for mysql does not help.
